# Count number of occurrences in a list from same turtle

Tags: netlogo

I would like to know how to find the 'source' of an item in a list. The actions that I need to consider for this task are the following:

1) an item is added in a list created by a turtle;

2) as each turtle has its own list with items created by different turtles, I would like to set a counter that says how often this turtle has picked turtle A's item.

**APPROACH & CODE:**

This piece of code adds an item (local variable) called 'this_item' in the selected turtle's list:

```
ask one-of turtles [

              set archive fput this_item archive
]
```

and this other code adds the same item to the neighbours' lists:

```
 ask in-link-neighbors [
              set archive fput this_item archive
]
```

I would set set a local variable, e.g. picked, as the first item from the list.

```
let picked first archive
```

To find the source of the item, I thought to use `who`. However, `who` is used for the turtle who adds the item to its own list, after extracted it.

```
print (word "Source: " who " has this list " list " after added item " picked)
```

If I consider a variable `source` defined as the source of the item by using myself when a turtle creates a new item, this reports me only the breed of the source (student), but not the corresponding turtle of the source (e.g. student 2). 
This makes impossible to count how many times one source's item has been selected.

**QUESTION:**

How can I count the number of time an item by the same turtle was selected?

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of to do this is to have each `this-item` be a two-element list, item 0 being the "item" itself and item 1 being the source turtle.  `this-item` would then be created by a turtle with

```
set this-item list x self
```

(Note that "item" itself is a reserved keyword, so my "item" is x.)  Any turtle that puts `this-item` in its list would then know that `item 0 this-item` was the thing itself and that `item 1 this-item` was the turtle from which it came.  To count the number of entries in a list, say `archive`, owned by a given turtle, say `turtle 1`, from a given turtle, say `turtle 3`, you could use

```
ask turtle 1 [show length filter [a -> item 1 a = turtle 3] archive]
```

If you need the number of times `turtle 3` has made entries in all turtles' archives, you can do it in steps. First create a list of all the archive lists.

```
let all-archives [archives] of turtles
```

Then use map to go through that list to make a list of the number of entries in each archive and sum that list.

```
show sum map [t -> length filter [a -> item 1 a = turtle 3] t ] all-archives
```

(I can't test this right now so check the syntax.) Of course, `turtles` could be a subset of all turtles if you like.

Comment: Thank you Charles for your help. You are right. I did not think of creating a list to collect information about the item and source. For my understanding and following what you suggested me, what I should have is a list of pairs `[(item source)]`. Then, once I have this list, by using the filter I should be able to find the pair that I would like to investigate (for example item 1 turtle 3 as in your example). By applying `length` I should get the number of item 1 in all the lists (source, because it generated the item, + neighbours if they picked this item and added it in their lists).

Comment: `Archive` has been defined as turtle-own so I cannot use it in an observer context. How could I use it to count the number of occurrence of a particular item (let's say `item 1` as in your example) in both creator's list and other turtles' lists (if the item is picked by them), by using `length`? should I use it in a procedure (to-report)? It is not clear to me how to connect the information from the `set this-item` and the `filter`. What I would like is to see how many time an items has been included in the lists of all the turtles, not a specific one.I hope you can help me

Comment: The `archive`  lists are turtle-own, so `length filter [a -> item 1 = turtle 3] archive` must indeed be used by a specific turtle who wants to know how many items from `turtle 3` are in her own archive. (`filter` produces a list of all such items and `length` counts the number of entries in that list.)  I will edit my answer above to show how one might get the number of entries `turtle 3` has made in all the archives, which I think is what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and for your help, Charles. I thought it could be also extended to all the turtles, but I might ask it in a new post. I do not know if you are able to answer also the following question, but I would like to try (maybe you know how to answer it just also by giving suggestions):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697955/reporting-in-a-chart-the-life-cycle-of-turtles.

Comment: I edited the syntax in this way: `show sum map [t -> length filter [a -> item 1 a = turtle 3] [ all-archives  ]] of all-turtles` but I got the following error: `ERROR: Expected closing bracket` (at the second "a"). Could you please tell me what I am still doing wrong?

Comment: I corrected a typo in my answer - In the last line of code,  `all-turtles` should have been `all-archives`. But to get to your question,  `all-archives` is already the list of all the turtles' archives, so `[all-archives ]] of all-turtles` doesn't really make sense. (And, if you really want all the turtles, simply using `turtles` will give your that agentset.) What were you after in your edited code?

Comment: Thank you so. much, Charles. I really appreciated it. I thought the syntax was wrong in the part of code that I edited (please my comment above). I had already changed  all-turtles with all-archives in my code, as I thought it was a typo (it may happen).