# Filtering in all lists by using two parameters

Tags: netlogo

Following the answer provided by an user to this question: [Count number of occurrences in a list from same turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761049/count-number-of-occurrences-in-a-list-from-same-turtle), I tried to use what he suggested to filter both items and turtles as follows:

```
show sum map [t -> length filter [a -> item 1 a = turtle 3] [ all-archives ]] of all-turtles
```

The code above should count how many times `item 1` created by `turtle 3` is included in the lists (`all-archives`) of all turtles (`all-turtles`). 
However, I have got the following error from the formula above:

> ERROR: Expected closing bracket

(at the second "a").

I am sure that there is still a syntax error in what I wrote, but I have not found any example using two parameters to be filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a misplaced `]`. Sometimes it is easier to break these long commands into pieces. The following code sets up a test by having two turtles put two entries in a given number of other turtles archives, as well as their own.  It then does the counting in pieces, and finally puts those pieces together in a single command. In your question, you use "all-turtles", but that is simply `turtles` in NetLogo. The last command looks only at a random subset of turtles.

```
turtles-own [ archive ]

to test
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [
    set archive []
  ]

  ask turtle 3 [
    let archive-entry list "at home" self
    set archive fput archive-entry archive
    ask n-of 30 other turtles [ set archive fput archive-entry archive ]
    set archive-entry list "not at home" self
    set archive fput archive-entry archive
    ask n-of 40 other turtles [ set archive fput archive-entry archive ]
  ]

   ask turtle 4 [
    let archive-entry list "at home" self
    set archive fput archive-entry archive
    ask n-of 20 other turtles [ set archive fput archive-entry archive ]
    set archive-entry list "not at home" self
    set archive fput archive-entry archive
    ask n-of 50 other turtles [ set archive fput archive-entry archive ]
  ] 
  ; get a list of all archives.
  let list-of-all-archives [archive] of turtles
  ; make a list of the number of occurrences we are looking for in each archive.
  let list-of-count-in-each-archive map [t -> length filter [a -> item 0 a = "at home" and item 1 a = turtle 3] t] list-of-all-archives
  ; sum up the number of occurences across all archives.
  show sum list-of-count-in-each-archive

  show sum map [t -> length filter [a -> item 0 a = "not at home" and item 1 a = turtle 3] t] [archive] of turtles
  show sum map [t -> length filter [a -> item 0 a = "at home" and item 1 a = turtle 4] t] [archive] of turtles
  show sum map [t -> length filter [a -> item 0 a = "not at home" and item 1 a = turtle 4] t] [archive] of turtles

  show sum map [t -> length filter [a -> item 0 a = "not at home" and item 1 a = turtle 4] t] [archive] of n-of 50 turtles
end
```